# How to add a call to action button next to (but not part of) the main navigation in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am building a site in Wordpress this week and I want to place a call to action at the top of the the site, but separate from the main navigation. Wordpress does not seem to offer this out of the box (think Donate button on Unicef site e.g.

[image: navigation example image]

I've tried using the Menuizer plugin it can add a button, but it places it at the end of the navigation, so that it is still wrapped up in the hamburger on mobile, I want it to appear as a seperate item like on (for example, unicef.org)

I don't also mind coding it by hand, but I don't really know where/how to do that.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set a new header menu location, in my opinion, you better duplicate from the existing menu you have.

Second, you create a menu item which later you'll be using as CTA button, probably it will pile up the current menu location, or the position maybe not right.

Third, customize it using css to have proper positioning.

Answer (score 0):

This is done directly from the template (If the template was created by you) But, something tells me that you are using a ready-made template then use the custom script

To insert the js code you сan use https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/ plugin or https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/

I can't see your html layout to help you with the selector, so try experimenting with this example:

```
<script>
    (function($) {          
        let selectorOfContainer = '.mybox',
                url = '#your-link',
                className = 'my-btn',
                btnLabel = 'DONATE';

        let $mybtn = $('<a/>', {
          class: className,
          href: url
        });

        $mybtn.text(btnLabel);

        $(selectorOfContainer).append($myBtn); // prepend, after, before

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Then use css styles to style your button

```
<style>
    .my-btn {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        color: #e25420;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .my-btn:hover, .my-btn:focus {
        background-color: #f0eded;
    }
</style>
```

It would be easier for me if I saw your site

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It seems that with hosted wordpress I am not able to change the theme php files and there is no way to do chmod without command line access. So I just decided add a button manually to the top of every page (i.e. directly after the navigation). It's not a great solution but as there aren't so many pages and they won't be updated very often I think it is workable.